# How to access web method path from the url obtained from AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my Springboot web application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk tomcat server. When i enter the url i am able to see the "Hello World' screen however i am unable to access the other web method paths by simply concatenating '\path' on the end.

How am i able to access my web method paths via the url provided by AWS?

Comment: If you start your application locally, are you able to browse other paths than /?
Do you upload your application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk console by clicking the button **Update and Deploy**?

Comment: What do you mean with "I am unable to access"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was not able to access this because i had not added a WebApplicationInitialiser to the main class.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
  return builder.sources(Application.class);
  }
}
```